# STOMP over websockets vs plain STOMP. Which one is better?

Tags: spring, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

As from spring 4, we have support of `STOMP` (sub)protocol over `WebSocket`. I do understand the benefits of `WebSocket` as compared to HTTP and the use & benefits of using `STOMP` over the `WebSocket` but I would like to understand the following:

1. Are there any Performance benefits of directly using the stomp protocol to talk with the MB (like RabbitMQ or Kafka - probably in future)
2. Is there any benefit of using `STOMP` as a sub-protocol over web-sockets other than to take care of the handshake required by the client to connect to the server/MB

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are orthogonal concerns.
Websocket is a transport; in fact, when using [sock.js](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client), you can use many transports as fallbacks and still use STOMP.

STOMP describes the message format exchanged between clients and servers.

It's like asking to compare TCP and HTTP.

1. You can't "just use" STOMP to communicate with a server or a message broker. You have to use a transport to send those STOMP messages.
2. STOMP doesn't take care of the websocket handshake, in fact, it's not aware of it at all. Case in point, you can transparently use STOMP on top of HTTP and see no difference from the STOMP perspective.

Comment: Regarding your point 1) As per the link https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html it seems that we can use web-stomp (over http) but the default STOMP/MQTT/AMQP mentioned doesn't use the HTTP. I am not sure how the handshake happens without the underlying HTTP but would have to investigate

Comment: But in the spring documentation at "26.4.14 STOMP Client" it is written that there's a STOMP over WebSocket and a STOMP over TCP client. So in my understanding WebSocket already builds on TCP so STOMP over TCP leaves the WebSocket layer in between out? So where would be the benifit in not leaving the WebSocket layer out? Edit: I want to communicate from server to server (so no browser involved)