# How to monitor server side event in spring MVC front end?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

This is my requirement

1. In my application Spring-mvc is internally hitting the rest api and fetching data from the dependent system(time consuming operation). I would like to monitor this server side event from JSP page
2. I would like to have timer/progress bar for the rest-api search triggered by spring.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can use the WebSocket and STOMP protocol for fulfill your requirement.

**WebSocket**

WebSocket is a bi-directional connection between user's browser and server. [for more info about WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

**STOMP Protocol**

STOMP is a simple (or streaming) text orientated messaging protocol for working with message-oriented middleware. [for more info about STOMP](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-stomp)

difference between WebSocket and STOMP protocol, [please refer Nitin Kamate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285813/8700934).

in this answer, used the SockJS and stopmjs to create a WebSocket and communication protocol in spring application.

**SockJS**

SockJS is a java script library for use to create WebSocket. [for more info about SockJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs) and [you can download sockjs.min.js file from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/master/dist/sockjs.min.js).

**stompjs**

stompjs is a java script library for provides a STOMP over WebSocket client for web browser. [for more info about stompjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stomp/stompjs) and [you can download stomp.min.js file from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stomp-js/stomp-websocket/master/lib/stomp.min.js).

you should download the sockjs.min.js and stomp.min.js files and add these java script files into your project and need to add WebSocket library dependancy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

firstly config the WebSocket in servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket.xsd">

    <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/portfolio"/>
            <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>

</beans>
```

- `application-destination-prefix` is used as prefix to massage mapping
- `path` - use the `http://localhost:8080/portfolio` url connect to WebSocket
- `prefix` is used as prefix to STOMP destination

then build the WebSocket client as follows,

in this example, we send the some value to destination from server side controller

AppController.java

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template; //provide methods for sending messages to a user

    @RequestMapping(value = "/event")
    public void getValue() throws InterruptedException{
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //in this example, used for loop to generate a value in iteration
            this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/number", i); //send the value of i to destination through WebSocket
            Thread.sleep(1000); //added a delay to every round in for loop
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript (SockJS) client for receiving value send by server side (java) event. (additionally used the angular library for handle the frontend. [tutorial for angular js](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/index.htm))

app.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
     
mainApp.controller('appController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.progress = 0; // variable declared by angular for store the value return by java
    var socket = new SockJS('/Your_Application_Name/portfolio'); //create a new SockJS WebSocket
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/number', function (value) {
        $scope.progress=value.body; //assigned value to progress variable
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    $scope.startEvent = function() { // this function call the getValue() function in controller
        $http.post('event').then(function(value) {

        }, function(reason) {
        
        }, function(value) {
        
        })
    }
}
});
```

following jsp file included with button and progress bar. use the button for start the server side event (in this example, button called `getValue()` function in `AppController.java` through angular js. additionally used bootstrap framework for create the frontend. [tutorial for bootstrap](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/index.htm))

index.jsp

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/sockjs.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/stomp.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/app.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="appController">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="progress  mb-3">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{width: progress + '%'}" aria-valuenow="{{progress}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{progress}}%</div>
            <!--progress variable used for set value to progress bar-->
         </div>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" ng-click="startEvent()">Start Event</button>
         <!--click event of above button call to startEvent() function in app.js file-->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

please refer spring documentation for more details about WebSocket, Spring WebSocket from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket).